# how to respond request only if it comes from one page?

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a php website. I have a page called pageX.php, and on that page I make an Ajax call:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "/getData/dat?q=" + str, true);
```

I want to avoid displaying data that is contained in this request. Also I want to be able to respond to this request only if it comes from pageX.php, and nowhere else.

I have tried using PHP sessions but it didn't work – the server still responds to the request if you go directly from the browser address bar to

> mysite.com/getData/dat?q=1

Can you help with a solution for this problem?

Comment: Just put a payload on the javascript request (for example name of the page) and then your server can check the payload if its what you need and respond to that request.

Comment: @Constantin this parametre will be visible for public , anyone can copy that name and past it on another browser or another machine and then get access to my data

Comment: Assign a SESSION variable with a unique value before the request, send it using another parameter and validate with the SESSION.

Comment: Ohh now it clarifies a bit what you need. You want all requests to come from ONE domain for example (your domain)... please check "CORS", it can be what you need... read on how to enable it on your server. This will accept requests only from domains that you are white-listing.

Comment: You want to implement RBAC, if your API route contains sensitive information then you should think about creating roles rather than sending ID's in a request to an open route. I think this is what you meant by "I tried with sessions". They should be stored prior to the request on the back-end, then a simple URL like `/getData` which already has the ID stored when the user authenticated.

Comment: You haven't made clear why you don't want to show the data on a direct request. Remember that even without it, I could retrieve the data from within your pageX.php. You should not consider data handled in Javascript as safe.

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried using sessions. I'd say that would be a quick and easy way to do it without going down the path of various Authentication protocols like OAuth.

Using sessions would mean that if you use the *same browser* as your current pageX.php, you *will* be able to access `mysite.com/getData/dat?q=1` from another tab.

This is because that browser would still be sending session cookies to your host. However, if you try using a new browser or a new device, you should not be able to make that request as you no longer have the same session cookies.

So your only risk is that someone else with access to your user's computer might be able to access PageX.php and their session.

So this is a good compromise, if you think that whoever is using PageX.php is not using it on a shared computer.

Answer (score 0):

**CORS** is not required to send requests to resources on the same domain since it is sent from the same origin. The issue here is that you have an open route which takes in arguments that respond with sensitive information based on that primary key. You need to close that route.

In order to do so, you can use something like [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to generate bearers for users. Sort of like, "Remember me tokens". This can be generated when the user authenticates and be stored as a session like so:

```
session_start();

/**
 * Your authentication logic here
 * Which for example returns a uid of 1
 */

$_SESSION['ssid'] = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode((object) ['uid' => 1], 'your_key');
```

Your closed route would now look something like this:

```
session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!isset(($bearer =& $_SESSION['ssid'])))
    die(json_encode(['error' => 403])); // Forbidden

try {
    $user = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($bearer, 'your_key', array('HS256'));
    // Your logic
    // $user->uid to get the ID
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exceptions where the bearer has either expired or is invalid
}
```

Then, (JQuery example) you'd be able to simply request the closed route like so:

```
(function ($) => {
    $.get('/getData', (response) => {
        // Logic
    });
})(JQuery);
```

This now stops users being able to forge the request with their own arguments.